Include built-in class in Matlab deployable archive
I'm compiling a deployable archive, aka CTF, with the mcc command to use it in Matlab Production Server.
I've a function that uses the built-in Parser class from the matlab.io.xml.dom namespace. It looks like the compiler does not add the class to the archive and/or Matlab Production Server can't use it. I'm getting: Unrecognized function or variable 'matlab.io.xml.dom.Parser'.
I've tried import matlab.io.xml.dom.* and import matlab.io.xml.dom.Parser, both result the same error. The Parser is used as the example suggest: doc = parseString(Parser,xmlString);
I've found a related question but I've two problems:

I don't necessarily know the path of the built in class on the build agent that is running the compilation so I'm not sure how to use the -I parameter
I'd always need to modify the build pipeline when I use a built-in class

Edit: I've extracted the erroneous part of the code into a new CTF and funnily it is not producing the error.
Matlab code:
function doSomething(XmlFile)
    if isfile(XmlFile)
        xml = xmlread(XmlFile);
    else
        if verLessThan('matlab','9.10')
            %throw error
        else
            import matlab.io.xml.dom.*
            xml = parseString(Parser,XmlFile);
        end
    end
end

Function signature:
{
    "_schemaVersion": "1.1.0",
    "importExample": {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "xmlData",
                "type": [],
                "purpose": ""
            }
        ],
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "output",
                "type": [],
                "purpose": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}

I compile it with:
mcc -U -W 'CTF:importExample,DISCOVERY:.\importExampleFunctionSignatures.json' importExample.m

I use Matlab 2021b. I admit that the question is now less concrete. I wonder what is the difference between the working and the non-working code.

Could you please post a [mre]? If you use a class in your code, it should automatically be included in the archive.

The linked question that references -I is not the same. There, the mcc program cannot find the functions used. In this question, if I understand it correctly, the compiler doesn’t complain, but the CTF doesn’t run because of missing code.

Thank you for your comment! I've extracted a few lines of code for the sake of the minimal example, however, the extracted code is working fine. My actual use-case is not really different, just some additional method calls.

Well, then you need to find out what is actually causing the issue. Please read the text of the linked [mre] page, and follow that recipe to find out what is actually causing the issue. Then we’ll be in a much better shape to understand why it’s causing the issue, and then to find a fix. Yes, it’s hard work to find the root cause, but that is what you need to do to fix this.

If I have an update I'm going to post it here
